# Systray issue : PydioSync v6

Tags: pantheon-files

Someone know how run pydio-ui here is the Binaries
https://pyd.io/apps/pydio-sync/

Output:
 message: I couldn't detect any system tray on this system.

Here what I need:
[image: Main]
Thanks in advance